# In Winforms what is the easiest way to have a "matrix" (rows of cells) input control?

Tags: c#, winforms, matrix

I have a need to have a user be able to input a matrix. 
The size will change depending on the users need, but 
it will be a rectangle, that is symmetrical (Is that the right term?)
6x4 ,10x2,8x8  (All rows will be the same length in a single matrix).

(Its actually  not for any matrix "math" manipulation).

I could use multiline text control delimited but I would prefer a grid.

I could use the gridview but it seems to be difficult to use in this manner.
I would prefer to make moving around in the grid very easy.

The user will be able to edit the matrix during the processing.

The one thing that makes this difficult is that the user needs to be able to
select and delete (or fill (different function)) a rectangle within the matrix.
So point at one cell and then drag pointer to highlight a subset of cells.

To clarify a little I used this extraxt from the Emacs user manual

Rectangle commands operate on rectangular areas of the text: all the characters between a certain pair of columns, in a certain range of lines. Emacs has commands to kill rectangles, yank killed rectangles, clear them out, fill them with blanks or text, or delete them. Rectangle commands are useful with text in multicolumn formats, and for changing text into or out of such formats.

Comment: Why don't use the `DataGridView`? What kind of difficulties you met? It suits your requirements best way, imho.

Comment: Ive been having some difficulty with the data binding. But I do believe you are right. Wish I could upvote you.

Comment: Thank you. I've created an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should use the `DataGridView` control. It suits your requirements best way, imho. Recreate its functionality is much harder than to overcome difficulties with data binding.

Answer (score 1):

In WinForm TableLayoutPanel control is what you need for this:
[TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Hmm. with a text box in each cell? It doesnt seem like it allows me to select across multiple cells?

Comment: True, i didnt get you in the original question. What problem you have with grids?

Comment: In TableLayuotPanel approach, you can place buttons in the bigining of the "rows" and read, copy to clipboard, clear contents, etc in those buttons click events. But the grid takes you closer to your objectives i think.